# NavigationView - adding menu items with C# results in NavigationViewItem being nested in a generated NavigationViewItem

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to add menu items to a NavigationView control via my code behind.

XAML:

```
<ct:NavigationView x:Name="NavMain" ItemInvoked="NavMain_ItemInvoked">
    <ct:NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <ct:NavigationViewItem Content="Home"/>
    </ct:NavigationView.MenuItems>
</ct:NavigationView>
```

C#:

```
private void RenderMenu()
{
    NavMain.MenuItems.Add(new NavigationViewItemSeparator());

    foreach (TarotSuit suit in deck.Suits)
    {
        // make a nav menu item for the suit
        NavigationViewItem newMenu = new NavigationViewItem();
        newMenu.Content = suit.Suit;
        newMenu.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.OutlineStar);

        NavMain.MenuItems.Add("menu");
    }
}
```

The menu renders, but it looks like the NavigationViewItem that's added is being set as the *content* of an automatically-generated NavigationViewItem, so the XAML tree and rendered menu look like this (there's too much padding on the left side due to this):

[image]

The sample code in Microsoft's docs uses the same syntax I'm using.

If I use a string, the menu item renders properly, but then I can't easily set any of the properties of the menu item. I know I can iterate back through the items to configure each one, but it seems like it should be rendering properly.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in the control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add new items from the code behind, it uses the default `NavigationViewItem` style for your new items and it should have the same style as the first `NavigationViewItem` you used in your xaml.

If you want to change the `NavigationViewItem` style, you can add a custom `NavigationViewItem` style resource in your page so that you can have the appearence you want.

---**Update**---

Okay, you used the [Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview), so if you want use the same style of `NavigationViewItem` style in the [NavigationView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview), you should also need to add the [Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.navigationviewitem) in your code behind.

In the code behind, add the namespace:

```
using MUXC = Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
```

Then you should create the new [Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.navigationviewitem) object then add them to your [NavigationView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview):

```
private void RenderMenu()
{
    NavMain.MenuItems.Add(new NavigationViewItemSeparator());

    foreach (TarotSuit suit in deck.Suits)
    {
        // make a nav menu item for the suit
        MUXC.NavigationViewItem newMenu = new MUXC.NavigationViewItem();
        newMenu.Content = suit.Suit;
        newMenu.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.OutlineStar);

        NavMain.MenuItems.Add(newMenu);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured out my problem - I needed to define using just Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationView, because I neeed Windows 10 Mobile support.

Comment: @ClairelyClaire I have added the update part in my answer, you should add the Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewItem, but not the default Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewItem. Please check my answer to get the details.

Comment: Oh...it seems you have solved your issue, glad about that:).